# Back slash appearing in CSS font declarations, not allowing web fonts to appear

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

So I've never seen this ever before and it has me stumped.

In chrome, my web fonts (served both from google and typekit) are not loading properly and when I look in my inspector at the CSS declarations for the fonts, it appears that there are random backslahes appearing in the actual font declaration that are essentially making them moot. I can't seem to reproduce the error in firefox or safari. Mostly wondering if anyone has ever seen this before/how did you deal with it?

Screenshot of the inspector is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yafmnpzb5ve4mf9/Screenshot%202014-02-24%2016.02.12.png

And the site itself is [bang-stage.dresgar.com](http://bang-stage.dresgar.com)

Any input would be great!!

Comment: The backslashes are actually there in your CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

The font declarations have the `/`s in the code.

I'm assuming this gargantuan css file is a compiled css file. The file that has the declarations in it (according to the code) is at:

```
/uploads/ultimatum/template_custom_2.css
```

the lines to fix look like:

```
h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: \"alternate-gothic-no-1-d\", \"Francois One\", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
```

and

```
#menu-main-menu .sub-container .sub-menu .menu-item > a {
    font-family: \"alternate-gothic-no-1-d\", \"Francois One\", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
```

I'm guessing that removing those slashes from the source should fix your problem.

Comment: Right, I guess I should have clarified, it is a compiled CSS file that is generated from the wordpress installation I am using. 

The thing is that these are not file path slashes. In fact, they don't even happen in other browsers, only in chrome. That's why i'm so confuzzled.

Comment: did you fix it? i am no longer seeing the issue in the stylesheet in Chrome when i go to http://bang-stage.dresgar.com/wp-content/uploads/ultimatum/598e7011b69b7fa92cce80bc45434f85.css?ver=3.8.1 and find "alternate-gothic". I was seeing the `\"` earlier.

Comment: fyi `\"` is how to escape a `"` in a php string.

Comment: Good to know! I actually didn't end up fixing it, I ended up going with a different type family served from typekit rather than google and it seemed to do the trick! Thanks for all your help!